# Vue How to show word limit in password input?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element-ui

I tried to use `show-word-limit` but it just works on common input.
Here is my code:

```
 <el-form
      label-position="right"
      :rules="rules" 
      ref="passwordData"
      :model="passwordData"
      label-width="80px"
      style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:30px">
          <el-row>
            <el-col :span="20">
          <el-form-item  label="原密码" prop="oldPassword" >
          <el-input v-model="passwordData.oldPassword" maxlength="12" show-word-limit type="password"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item  label="新密码" prop="newPassword" >
          <el-input v-model="passwordData.newPassword" maxlength="12" show-word-limit type="password"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item  label="确认密码" prop="newPassword_confirm">
          <el-input v-model="passwordData.newPassword_confirm" maxlength="12" show-word-limit type="password"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-button @click="submitForm('passwordData')">保存</el-button>
        <el-button @click="restorePasswordData()">返回</el-button>
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
      </el-form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [docs](https://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-US/component/input#input-attributes), the `show-word-limit` can only be used on `input:text` or `textarea`.

If you need to display the limit anyway, you can try an "homemade" solution; however, it is generally a bad security usage to limit the number of characters for a password field, because the longer the password generally the safer.